# Doppler Shift and Wireless Access Points

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, motion, doppler

I am trying to design and implement a system that would calculate the velocity of a hand motion in smartwatch.

The general idea is to calculate the Doppler Shift of each access point and find velocity. I have 4 wireless access points I can use. Please also assume I have a 5 seconds long downsampled and downconverted baseband signals received on smart watch from each of the 4 access points. My question is how can I calculate the doppler shift from the sampled signals and how can I then find the velocity of hand motion? I also know 3D coordinates of each access point and coordinates of my hand. Do I take the FFT of the sample and then analyze it in the frequency domain for an offset? If so, can anyone provide some more detail?

Comment: first, give your self a few rough number: what's the maximum doppler shift you're expecting? How is that number in relation to the frequency accuracy of your sampling? How is that number in relation to the variance of a best case frequency estimator (Cramer-Rao)